# Rtools not found by devtools, but ls and gcc are on PATH

Tags: r, r-devtools

```
Sys.which('gcc')
                                                                 gcc 
"C:\\Users\\[redacted]\\Documents\\aps\\Rtools\\mingw_32\\bin\\gcc.exe" 

Sys.which('ls')
                                                       ls 
"C:\\Users\\[redacted]\\Documents\\aps\\Rtools\\bin\\ls.exe" 

find_rtools(cache=FALSE,debug=TRUE)

Scanning path...
ls : C:\Users\[redacted]\Documents\aps\Rtools\bin\ls.exe 
"C:/Users/[redacted]/Documents/aps/rportnov/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD  \
  config CC 

Scanning registry...
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but is not currently installed.

Please download and install Rtools 3.4 from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/.
```

Comment: How did you install Rtools? The `find_rtools` function looks for specific registry keys to verify installation. From the output it would appear those are not present. Specifically it looks for `SOFTWARE\R-core\Rtools` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`

Comment: I have installed normally, without admin rights, in a personal folder.

Comment: I assume you downloaded the most recent version? Was there an option during installation to set registry keys? Did you un-select that? Can you use regedit to verify that those keys exist?

Comment: Maybe also let us know which version of devtools you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem in the registry generated during installation, so I reinstalled it and it worked.